# FMX firemonkey how to Scroll a vertical scroll box in runtime

Tags: delphi, scrollbar, firemonkey

Somebody can help me how to scroll a vertical scrollbar in firemonkey in runtime, there is a property scrollby, but it didnt work, I don't have any ideia how to solve it.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There is no independent vertical scroll bar component in FMX. There are however several scroll box components. A `TVertScrollbox` (VSB) is one of them. If you use that, you can safely set `VSB.Align := TAlignlayout.Client`. The VSB never scrolls itself! It only scrolls the content if the content exceeds the vertical dimension of the VSB.

You can put a `TLayout` on the VSB, then set it's alignment to `VertCenter`, and it's `Height` to `VSB.Height * 2`. At runtime, the vertical scrollbar will appear, and you will be able to scroll the layout up and down. After this, you can adjust the position of the layout on the screen by calling the `Scrollby` and `ViewPortPosition` methods of the VSB.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `TScrollBox` set `TAlignlayout.Client` then put the components inside the `Tscrollbox` and set them `TAlignlayout.top` and Done! When the content exceeds the vertical dimension the scroll will appear.

Answer (score 0):

in delphi and C ++ Builder in FMX you can use ScrollBy (int, int); to move the scroll

Exemple:

```
      this->ScrollBox->ScrollBy(0, - this->ScrollBox->Width);
```

I used a negative value because this will make the scroll move downwards following the pre-filling of items.